# Can I use Pixabay API in My Wallpaper App?

Tags: api, android-studio, policy, wallpaper, pixabay

I recently created a wallpaper app.
I want to ask, do Pixabay allow to show their photos as wallpaper in a Wallpaper Application. Isn't there any policy restrictions for wallpaper apps in Pixabay.

Website:
[pixabay.com](https://pixabay.com)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
The PHP library I tested is from [Zoonman PHP API Code on GitHub](https://github.com/zoonman/pixabay-php-api)

Then obtain a Developer Account on [Pixabay Developer API](https://pixabay.com/id/service/about/api/)

There after install the library on your server and obtaining images URLs etc is just simple like this code asking for images on 'nature'. Change the query keyword and you will get images for that.

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$pixabayClient = new \Pixabay\PixabayClient([
  'key' => 'yourPixabayKey'
]);

// test it
$results = $pixabayClient->get(['q' => 'nature'], true);
// show the results
var_dump($results);
```

Use data fields returned by the API to create your wallpaper App gallery.

Comment: I Asked about Android Application, that, isn't there any policy restriction for wallpaper app.

Comment: Pixabay license page specifially mentioned against distribution on wallpaper platforms. "Don't redistribute or sell Pixabay content on other stock or wallpaper platforms." The license page is here if you want to read all their terms : https://pixabay.com/id/service/license/